# count the pairs in a set of Data

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

I have a list of Data, e.g.,

```
list1={0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}

list2={0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0}
```

and I want to get as an output `True` or `False` if I have only even number of Data of similar or not. in the above example I like to write a code that returns False for `list1` and True for `list2`, since in `list1` I have only one 0, but in the `list2` there are even number of each number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html)

```
f = And @@ EvenQ[Values[Counts[#]]] &
{f[list1], f[list2]}
```

> {False, True}

Comment: +1. Or `f = Counts /* AllTrue[EvenQ]`

Comment: Yours is much concise. I think you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I did, but when I saw yours, I deleted it :)  I shall undelete.

Answer (score 11):

Given:

```
f = Counts /* AllTrue[EvenQ];
```

Then:

```
f[list1]
(* False *)

f[list2]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Tally function:

> Tally[list]
>   tallies the elements in list, listing all distinct
>   elements together with their multiplicities.

So as

```
And@@EvenQ[Tally[list1][[;; , 2]]]
```

or

```
And@@EvenQ[Tally[list2][[;; , 2]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
check[list_] := If[
  Cases[EvenQ[Count[list, #] & /@ Union[list]], False] == {},
  True, False]

check[list2]
```

> True