# determine the structure of Data in sum of two subsets Modulus $n$

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures, subset

I wrote a code below to determine the cases when two subsets of a set $\mathbb{Z_n}=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ are added together element by element (without removing the multiplicity) in $\mathbb{Z_n}$ and see if there are pairs with even  in each number or not, but it takes long time to run it when the number $n$ go bigger than 10. I am asking for a faster code. In some step I used the comment of people here :)  [count the pairs in a set of Data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159043/count-the-pairs-in-a-set-of-data).

```
Clear[M,A,B,n,d,f]
Z[n_]:=Table[i,{i,0,n-1}]
n=4;
p[A_,B_]:=
Union[Flatten[Table[If[SubsetQ[Z[n],A]==True&&SubsetQ[Z[n],B]==True&&
Length[A]==4&&MemberQ[A,0]==True&&MemberQ[A,a]==True&&MemberQ[B,b]==True,
Mod[a+b,n],{}],{a,A},{b,B}],0]]

f=And@@EvenQ[Values[Counts[#]]]&;
d=Union[
Flatten[Table[
Sort[Flatten[p[A,B]]],{A,Subsets[Z[n]]},{B,Subsets[Z[n]]}],1]]
g=f/@d
Sort[g]
```

The output for $n=4$ is

```
{{}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}}


{True, False, True, False, True}

{False, False, True, True, True}
```

The `True` and `False` were explained in the previous question with quoted link above.

P.S. Let me give an example: Let n=4, and A={0,1,2,3}, B={0,1}, then 
A+B={0,1,2,3,1,2,3,0}, where the last 0 is 4(mod4). As we see that in the set A+B we have two 0, two 1, two 2 and two 3, therefore the final output for this set is `True`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for, but your example can be coded quite concisely. The Outer calculates all the direct sums, the Mod reduces back to the range 0 to n-1, and the Tally counts how many of each element occur.

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3}; b = {0, 1};
tally = Tally[Mod[Outer[Plus, b, a] // Flatten, 4]]

{{0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

You can determine whether all elements occur an even number of times using EvenQ:

```
EvenQ[tally[[All, 2]]]
```